# How to modify datatable button export extension?

Tags: datatables

When I apply try to apply jquery datatable with export extension, the "show no entries" disappear, I want to keep it while also having the buttons.

```
$('#tb_user').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip', // disappear because of that line
      "processing":true,
      "buttons":['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
      "order":[],
      "columnDefs":[{"targets":[0, 9],"orderable":false}]
    });
```

Also it is possible to pdf/print only certain column that you want to, like if I dont want to print the last column in the CRUD table cause I dont need it for print.

Comment: For the last part, this have been asked multiple times also. See for example this -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512860/how-to-use-export-excel-and-print-for-selected-columns-in-datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36512860/1407478)

Comment: It not working, could you please help me `"buttons":[
                            {
                                extend: 'excel'
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
                                }},
                            {
                                extend: 'print'
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
                                }}],` Maybe cause of the { }?

Comment: Try look at the missing comma. Elements in a literal is separated by commas. Sad the linked answer have this error, did not notice it, but this is obviously the reason :)

Comment: Here is a working example -> **https://jsfiddle.net/2nwqa2jk/65/**